# Failed Authorization in Postman using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Ruby on Rails API with a group of people via Github. For some reason, my authorization fails repeatedly and says the following in my server.

```
Started GET "/boards" for ::1 at 2020-08-24 21:38:38 -0400
Processing by BoardsController#index as */*
Filter chain halted as :authorized rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 150)
```

Any ideas on what may be happening here? Boards is a controller I created and I am trying to index it. It additionally doesn't work with a post method either.

Comment: The 'filter chain halted...' message happens when your controller has a ``before_action`` callback (``:authorized``) that is forcing a render or redirecting (which terminates remaining request processing). Assuming that you're using something like JWT for authentication/authorization, you'll want to ensure you've got Postman set up to pass a valid JWT token in the headers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly either not sending any credentials in your requests from Postman, or the credentials you are sending are incorrect.

You can see information about making Postman send credentials as part of your request in the Postman docs at https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/

In order to know what you need to send, you would need to know what authentication mechanism you're using. With an API, this is most likely a JWT and you are most likely using the Devise gem, but something else may have been configured in your app.

In the case of it being JWT, you would need to generate a valid JWT in your application, then configure Postman's authorization to use "Bearer Token", providing the token you generated as the value there